# Erro: Operação entre threads inválida

Tags: c#

Estou tentando abrir a Webcam, porém toda vez que tento executar o método `iniciarwebcam()` ele me retorna o erro:

> Ocorreu uma exceção do tipo "System.InvalidOperationException" em
>   System.Windows.Forms.dll, mas ela não foi manipulada no código do
>   usuário Operação entre threads inválida: controle 'Form1' acessado de
>   um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.

Como estou aprendendo C# agora to com difuldades de encontrar uma solução que se encaixem com a minha

O erro acontece na linha:

```
video.NewFrame += (s, b) => pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)b.Frame.Clone();
```

Código:

```
using AForge.Video.DirectShow;

public void  inciarwebcam() 
{

    FilterInfoCollection filtro = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

    if (filtro != null)
    {
        video = new VideoCaptureDevice(filtro[0].MonikerString);
        video.NewFrame += (s, b) => pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)b.Frame.Clone();
        video.Start();
    }
}

public void fecharwebcam() 
{

    if (video != null && video.IsRunning ) {

        video.SignalToStop();
        video = null;

    }

}

public VideoCaptureDevice video;

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (button6.Text == "Desativado")
    {
        button6.Text = "Ativado";
        button6.BackColor = Color.Green;
       ard.Open();
        inciarwebcam();
    }
    else
    {
        button6.BackColor = Color.DarkRed;
        button6.Text = "Desativado";
        ard.Close();

        fecharwebcam();
    };
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Possivelmente o evento `NewFrame` é assíncrono, e ao tentar acessar o  `pictureBox1` a exceção é disparada.

Você pode utilizar um invoke para isso:

```
video.NewFrame += (s, b) => pictureBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker) delegate {
                            pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)b.Frame.Clone();
            });
```

Me parece que dessa forma pode ficar um pouco lento, já que a cada frame vai ir na outra thread mostrar a imagem. É só um ponto de partida, se tiver a documentação do que está usando pode facilitar as coisas

---

Edit:

Tenho um form com a mesma biblioteca, e no exemplo que utilizei, há uma variável no form, que recebe a imagem, e depois é aplicada no `picturebox`:

```
Bitmap Imagem;
private void video_NovoFrame(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventArgs)
{
    Imagem = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    pbCaptura.Image = Imagem;
}
```

Comment: Cara, muito obrigado! Funcinou e eu não tenho a documentação... Peguei em um tutorial, mas mesmo assim, obrigado!

Comment: olha a atualização @DanielSouto, acho que dessa segunda forma fica melhor

Answer (score 0):

Pode sempre validar se o controlo precisa efetivamente de evocar o `Invoke`:

```
video.NewFrame += (s, b) => 
{
    if(pictureBox1.InvokeRequired)
        pictureBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => { pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)b.Frame.Clone(); }));
    else pictureBox1.Image = (Bitmap)b.Frame.Clone();
}
```