# C# Backgroundworker

Tags: c#

Ola, estou com a seguinte mensagem, é a primeira vez q estou trabalhando com Backgroundworker e executo uma função longa dento da função (DoWork) do Backgroundworker porem ele acontece essa mensagem e nao executa esse lbMSG é uma LABEL aonde eu mostro algumas mensagens, então oq ja fiz comentei a LABEL mas ai da erro em outras partes com a mesma mensagem. ( System.InvalidOperationException: 'Operação entre threads inválida: controle 'lbMSG' acessado de um thread que não é aquele no qual foi criado.' )

Esse é o codigo do (DoWork)

```
       private void bcwLeDbf_DoWork(object sender, System.ComponentModel.DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        //Executa a tarefa
        ConectaDBF("select * from " + CaminhoArquivo);
        //Verifica se houve uma requisição para cancelar a operação.
        if (bcwLeDbf.CancellationPending)
        {
            //se sim, define a propriedade Cancel para true
            //para que o evento WorkerCompleted saiba que a tarefa foi cancelada.
            e.Cancel = true;
            return;
        }
    }
```

Se alguém tiver alguma dica agradeço.

Comment: você tem a variavel ConectaDBF e CaminhoArquivo?

Comment: o BackgroundWorker trabalha em uma thread diferente da thread principal da aplicação onde é criada a parte visual... então você não pode simplesmente acessar um controle que foi criado na thread principal de dentro do backgroundworker. Para uma resposta adequada, deveria ter o código do método `ConectaDBF` sem isso não posso apontar onde está o erro. Dá uma olhada em outros exemplos de background worker, e como usar o report progress. Há ainda a opção de usar o `Invoke`: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/324491/69359

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente na propriedade `CaminhoArquivo` ou no método `ConectaDBF` você está buscando o valores da tela. Estou assumindo isso, pois faltam informações no seu trecho de código.

Mas o ponto é que, isso não é possível. Pois as referencias de memória não existem na thread que executa o evento `DoWork`.

Para fazer essa operação, você deveria passar os valores por parâmetro na execução do seu `BackgroundWorker`.

Exemplo:

```
//Aqui você passa os valores da sua tela por parametro
backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(CaminhoArquivo);
```

E dentro do seu método DoWork, você pega o valor da seguinte forma:

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    //Executa a tarefa
    ConectaDBF("select * from " + (string)e.Argument); //Aqui você pega pelo e.Argument
}
```

Outro ponto é que você pode utilizar o evento `ProgressChanged` que será executado na thread principal da sua aplicação.

Para isso, basta fazer uma chamada como essa:

```
backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(10);
```

Não esqueça de alterar a propriedade `WorkerReportsProgress` para `true`, caso deseje utilizar este exemplo acima.

Comment: Na verdade ele não chega na atribuição da variável CaminhoArquivo a Label é a primeira coisa q essa função ConectaDBF faz.